# Find all objects in List<T> with same property value

Tags: search, c#-4.0, comparison

I have a class Card, which has property Rank (1,2,3 etc) and I have a list of Cards and I wish to find all the Cards with the same Rank value in that list.

The list of Cards is sorted by Rank beforehand.

What would be the fasted way in .NET (using LINQ, if possible) to find all the objects with the same property value.

I don't know what the property value is beforehand, so I have to go through and compare.  Until now I've been looping and keeping references to previous objects to compare, but I was wondering if there is not some easier way to do this?

Point is I need to be able to find N elements in a list with the same property value.

There might not be, but I thought I'd still ask.

Comment: I imagine you mean a *class* rather than an *object* Card, right? Also, I imagine you want to find all objects with the same property *value* rather than the same *property*? If this is OK, you may want to edit your question for the sake of clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group the cards by rank:

```
public class Card
{
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var cards = new[] 
        {
            new Card { Rank = 1 },
            new Card { Rank = 2 },
            new Card { Rank = 3 },
            new Card { Rank = 2 },
            new Card { Rank = 1 },
        };

        var groups = cards.GroupBy(x => x.Rank);
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cards with rank {0}", group.Key);
            foreach (var card in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(card.Rank);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest would be to use linq

```
var results = myCardList.Select( c=>c.rank == myRank );
```

then you can iterate or convert to list.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Enumerable.ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx). The cards does not have to be sorted beforehand.

If you have a class

```
public class Card
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a Lookup that groups per `Rank` like this

```
var cards = new Card[]{
    new Card{Rank = 1, Name = "A"},
    new Card{Rank = 1, Name = "B"},
    new Card{Rank = 2, Name = "C"},
    new Card{Rank = 3, Name = "D"},
};

var cardsByRank = cards.ToLookup(card => card.Rank);

foreach (var cardRankGroup in cardsByRank)
{
    Console.WriteLine("KEY: " + cardRankGroup.Key);

    foreach (var card in cardRankGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   Card: " + card.Name);
    }
}
```

with the output

```
KEY: 1
   Card: A
   Card: B
KEY: 2
   Card: C
KEY: 3
   Card: D
```

**Edit**
if you want to extract all cards for a given Rank you can use rank as index to the lookup

```
foreach (var card in cardsByRank[2])
{
    Console.WriteLine("   Card: " + card.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Tony, are you looking for something link this?

```
List<Card> rankedCards = cards.Where(o=> o.Rank == rank).ToList()
```

This should return a list of Cards that match the variable "rank" which I assume contains an int containing the value of Rank you want to match.